# Excel VBA - Import Macro that works but doesn't

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Macro -

```
Sub Import_Data()

Dim rng As Range
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim FName As String
Dim c1 As Worksheet
Set c1 = Sheets("c")

    FName = Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00") & ".xlsm")
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName)

    c1.Range("L2:O6").Value = WB2.Worksheets(2).Range("M2:P6").Value

    c1.Range("L14:O18").Value = WB2.Worksheets(2).Range("M14:P18").Value

WB2.Close

End Sub
```

When i run it i get the following error

[image]

So, the worksheet is there, i can open the worksheet but it won't accept it for some reason. Also, what's weird is that if i changed the file name of the worksheet it's looking for to "Fruit w32.xlsm", when i run the macro, the wildward will find "Fruit" but it will just say "Fruit" in the blank space in the picture

It worked perfectly fine but now it's having real issues and I don't understand why. Any Ideas?

EDIT: If i get rid of the Dir() part it works fine

Comment: Have you checked the value of FName?

Comment: Yeah, so its value is the filename + .xlsm However it doesn't have the whole path beforehand. Is that the issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding the path in the open line? `Filename:=activeworkbook.path & "\" & fname)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dir function only returns the filename if found, so you have to specificy the path on opening.

```
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
FName = Dir(FPath & "\*w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00") & ".xlsm")
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName)
```